# MathJax Firefox rendering issues

Tags: bug, firefox, mathjax, page-rendering

I recently noticed that MathJax items are not rendered in firefox, but render perfectly in chrome.

[image: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229480/why-is-7-tev-considered-as-a-big-amount-of-energySystem]

(here is the link - [Why is 7 TeV considered as a big amount of energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229480/why-is-7-tev-considered-as-a-big-amount-of-energySystem))

### Details:

- Windows 10 build 10586
- Firefox 43.0.4
- Chrome 47.0.2526.111

I have tested this one only one other computer with the same specs and it has the issue as well.

### Edit

Here is the request page for firefox:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on the same specs. Have you tried opening the Developer Tools and looking at either the Console or Network tabs to see if it's either erroring out or not getting loaded at all?

Comment: I have now. The requests look right, though I'm not familiar with MathJax. See above for a screen shot.

Comment: @animuson I just noticed that if I open the page in a new tab, but don't look at it, the formulas were rendered properly. (click and drag the link to the tab area and DON'T let it take you to the page, wait for it to load, and enjoy the formula ;). This is a very strange bug...

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console? Have you tried clearing your browser cache, disabling plugins etc?

Comment: Hmm, I'm clearly not up to speed on web tool debugging techniques. Restarting firefox with plugins disabled worked, and I think the culprit is a greasemonkey script I wrote, but I don't know why... Thanks anyway!